# How can run multiple celery tasks in parallel (by using group)?

Tags: python, celery, worker, celery-task

I am new to Celery. I want to run demo_task in parallel, but it runs tasks sequentially instead of in parallel. Please let me know if I did something wrong.

```
import time
from celery import Celery
from celery import chain, group, chord, chunks
import pandas as pd

CONFIG = {
    'BROKER_URL': 'redis://localhost:6379/0',
    'CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND': 'redis://localhost:6379/0',
}

app = Celery()
app.config_from_object(CONFIG)


@app.task(name='demo_task')
def demo_task(x, y):
    print("demo_task", x, y)
    pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [2, 3, 4]}).to_csv(f"demo{x}.csv", index=False)
    print("saved")
    time.sleep(8)


def run_task():
    print("start chain_call")
    t = group(*[demo_task.signature((3, 3)),
                demo_task.signature((4, 4)),
                demo_task.signature((5, 5))]
              ).apply_async()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_task()
```

[Command]

celery -A celery_demo worker -l info --pool=solo --purge

[Log]

```
[2022-04-22 16:29:51,668: WARNING/MainProcess] Please run `celery upgrade settings path/to/settings.py` to avoid these warnings and to allow a smoother upgrade to Celery 6.0.  
[2022-04-22 16:29:51,668: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0  
[2022-04-22 16:29:51,668: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors  
[2022-04-22 16:29:52,672: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone  
[2022-04-22 16:30:05,602: WARNING/MainProcess]  
[2022-04-22 16:30:05,602: WARNING/MainProcess] 4  
[2022-04-22 16:30:05,602: WARNING/MainProcess]  
[2022-04-22 16:30:05,602: WARNING/MainProcess] 4  
[2022-04-22 16:30:05,602: WARNING/MainProcess] saved  
[2022-04-22 16:30:13,614: INFO/MainProcess] Task demo_task[c017c03e-b49d-4d54-85c5-4af57dd55908] succeeded in 8.016000000061467s: None  
[2022-04-22 16:30:13,614: INFO/MainProcess] Task demo_task[d60071c6-4332-4ec1-88fd-3fce79c06ab5] received  
[2022-04-22 16:30:13,614: WARNING/MainProcess] demo_task  
[2022-04-22 16:30:13,614: WARNING/MainProcess]  
[2022-04-22 16:30:13,614: WARNING/MainProcess] 5  
[2022-04-22 16:30:13,614: WARNING/MainProcess]  
[2022-04-22 16:30:13,614: WARNING/MainProcess] 5  
[2022-04-22 16:30:13,614: WARNING/MainProcess] saved  
[2022-04-22 16:30:21,634: INFO/MainProcess] Task demo_task[d60071c6-4332-4ec1-88fd-3fce79c06ab5] succeeded in 8.015000000130385s: None
```

Comment: does the * before the list unpack the list into args?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you expect tasks to run in parallel if you use the "solo" pool?

Instead, start with the prefork concurrency (the default): `celery -A celery_demo worker -l info -c 8`

This will make Celery worker spawn 8 worker processes that can execute tasks in parallel. If your machine has more than 8 cores then you could increase that number from 8 to N where N is number of cores available on the host machine. I always go for N-1 to let the system have one more spare core for some other stuff.

Prefork concurrency is great for CPU-bound tasks. If your tasks are more about I/O, then give the "gevent" or "eventlet" concurrency type a try.

Comment: Now it works on Linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your run_task function

```
async def run_task():
    print("start chain_call")
    t = await group(*[demo_task.signature((3, 3)),
            demo_task.signature((4, 4)),
            demo_task.signature((5, 5))]
          ).apply_async()
```

Comment: I change run_task() to asyncio.run(run_task()), and I got error message TypeError: object GroupResult can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: Celery is not yet ready for async/await. Since Celery predates async/await it has own way to work with asynchronous execution. I am sure this will change in the (distant) future.